# Развернуть базу данных из бэкапа на удаленной машине

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Я пытаюсь перенести базу данных с локальной машины на удаленную.
Из локального `SQL Server` я создаю backup и сохраняю его в расшаренную папку на удаленном компьютере(`\\SERVER228\SharedFolder\`).
На удаленном компьютере также имеется `SQL Server`, и я собираюсь сделать `RESTORE DATABASE` из этого `backup` файла, имея `ConnectionString` к удаленному `SQL Server`'у.
Команда `RESTORE DATABASE` требует параметр `FROM DISK`, в котором указывается имя `backup` файла (`'D:\Shared\RetardsDB.bak'`).

Могу ли я узнать по сетевому имени папки её физический адрес для того, чтобы запустить `RESTORE DATABASE` команду напрямую?
И если да, то как я могу это сделать?
Пишу на C#.

Comment: Сохранить backup файл на общий диск, к которому имеют доступ ваши удаленные серверы. Затем программно скопировать его в локальный 'c:\temp' Тогда ваш «из файла» просто укажет на эту папку: 'c:\temp\RetardsDB.bak'

Comment: @user270576 SQL Server только из бэкапа на локальном ПК может восстановить БД.

Comment: Да, я понял это и обновил свой комментарий

Comment: "SQL Server только из бэкапа на локальном ПК может восстановить БД" - Грубо говоря, это не так. Обычно учетная запись, под которой работает SQL-сервер, не имеет доступа к сети. Но вы все равно можете выполнить изнутри SQL "EXEC xp_cmdshell 'NET USE Z: \\Shared\Backup'"

Answer (score 2):

Через WMI:

Вот пример получения полной информации:

```
  private DataTable GetSharedFolderAccessRule()
    {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            DT.Columns.Add("ShareName");
            DT.Columns.Add("Caption");
            DT.Columns.Add("Path");
            DT.Columns.Add("Domain");
            DT.Columns.Add("User");
            DT.Columns.Add("AccessMask");
            DT.Columns.Add("AceType");

            ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\cimv2");
            Scope.Connect();
            ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting");
            ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
            ManagementObjectCollection QueryCollection = Searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject SharedFolder in QueryCollection)
            {
                {
                    String ShareName = (String) SharedFolder["Name"];
                    String Caption   = (String)SharedFolder["Caption"];
                    String LocalPath = String.Empty;
                    ManagementObjectSearcher Win32Share = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Path FROM Win32_share WHERE Name = '" + ShareName + "'");
                    foreach (ManagementObject ShareData in Win32Share.Get())
                    {
                        LocalPath = (String) ShareData["Path"];
                    }

                    ManagementBaseObject Method = SharedFolder.InvokeMethod("GetSecurityDescriptor", null, new InvokeMethodOptions());
                    ManagementBaseObject Descriptor = (ManagementBaseObject)Method["Descriptor"];
                    ManagementBaseObject[] DACL = (ManagementBaseObject[])Descriptor["DACL"];
                    foreach (ManagementBaseObject ACE in DACL)
                    {
                        ManagementBaseObject Trustee = (ManagementBaseObject)ACE["Trustee"];

                        // Full Access = 2032127, Modify = 1245631, Read Write = 118009, Read Only = 1179817
                        DataRow Row = DT.NewRow();
                        Row["ShareName"]  = ShareName;
                        Row["Caption"]    = Caption;
                        Row["Path"]       = LocalPath;
                        Row["Domain"]     = (String) Trustee["Domain"];
                        Row["User"]       = (String) Trustee["Name"];
                        Row["AccessMask"] = (UInt32) ACE["AccessMask"];
                        Row["AceType"]    = (UInt32) ACE["AceType"];
                        DT.Rows.Add(Row);
                        DT.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
        }

        return DT;
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567063/get-a-list-of-all-unc-shared-folders-on-a-local-network-server

Comment: `\\.\root\cimv2` - это имя сетевой папки? То есть мне указывать `\\SERVER228\SharedFolder`?

Comment: Это пространство имён. Ничего менять не надо - перестанет работать. Приведённый код запускать на удалённом сервере. А если код надо запускать на рабочей станции, то заменить точку на имя сервера, получится `\\SERVER228\root\cimv2`.

Comment: Изменил. Эх, падает с эксепшеном "Отказано в доступе. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))". Но огромное спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @KamikyIT, по идее, вы должны быть админом, что бы посылать удаленные запросы WMI.

Comment: @iluxa1810 не совсем. Я работаю над программой, которая будет работать со многими серверами.

Comment: @KamikyIT если машины в одном домене, то заведите какую нибудь сервисную учётку.